# How can I toggle url when click back button on browser?

Tags: javascript, browser

I want redirect to the url when user click back button on browser, and if user click back again, they will come to previous url, I mean it toggle of each url, I try the code bellow but it work not correctly. It recognize when click back 2-3 times on PC, and on mobile, it doesn't work.

```
<script>
        window.history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
        window.history.back();
        window.history.forward();
        let k=0;
        let counttime = 3;
        window.onpopstate = function(){
            k++;
            if(k >(counttime)){
                window.location.href="https://google.com";
                return false;
            }
            else{
                window.history.go(1);
            }
        };
    </script>
```

Comment: `
history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {
    history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
});
`
you can try this code to prevent from going back. But clicking double will go back

Comment: @SifatHaque so anyway for click just once ? :D